# How to show Time.now based on TimeZone - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hey guys i am trying to show server time but instead it shows local time. Is it possible to set server timezone to something like canada?

i tried this in `application.rb`

`config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'`

but when i use `Time.now` it shows local time.

Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time.now will always print your system local time. If you want to print current time according to zone, then use:

```
Time.zone.now
```

Or,

```
Time.now.in_time_zone(Central Time (US & Canada))
```

Comment: thank you this did the trick! can i also ask if changing time zone if it interferes with saved datetime of activerecord?

Comment: Time is stored in utc format in database. Changing the timezone will parse time accordingly but does not change it in database.

Comment: awesome thank you very much for your help and fast responses!

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`Time.current`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-current). Quote from its docs:

> `Time.current` returns `Time.zone.now` when `Time.zone` or `config.time_zone` are set, otherwise just returns `Time.now`.